# Who's writing my journal?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I was looking through some old journal entries today when it clicked with me that Geralt can't be the one writing down these journal entries, since it discusses Geralt in the third-person. Furthermore, the writer refers to himself in the first-person in several of the entries. I can't recall who I was bumping into during those quests, so this confuses me. Who writes these journal entries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you open your <kbd>J</kbd>ournal, Dandelion has this to say about himself:

> It is always awkward to write about
>   onself, yet I cannot shirk this duty.
>   In an effort to preempt any
>   accusations of partiality, **I shall set
>   down the humblest of notes, relating
>   only the best-known facts.** Dandelion
>   -- in reality the viscount de Lettenhove, though titles are
>   unimportant -- is a certified
>   troubadour, a lecturer at Oxenfurt
>   University, a persona known among
>   society as a charmer, poet, dandy and
>   unparalleled lover. Almost everyone
>   north of the Yaruga has heard of him,
>   and those who have not are either
>   boors or simpletons or both, as a
>   result of which their opinions do not
>   matter in the slightest. Dandelion
>   played a significant part in the most
>   important events of the era. He loved,
>   fought, negotiated, and acquired
>   immense knowledge, even that of the
>   forbidden variety. His works are a
>   testimony of the times, but it is his
>   moving poetic tropes that have brought
>   him true fame. The important thing in
>   this story is that Dandelion was a
>   friend to Geralt of Rivia -- possibly
>   his only true friend. He was Geralt's
>   confidant, advisor and companion in
>   misery (for it was impossible to
>   experience good fortune in the
>   witcher's company). What Geralt did,
>   Dandelion faithfully recounted, and
>   one should not give credence to those
>   who accuse this humble chronicler of
>   confabulating.
>
> Discretion -- a virtue I have always
>   professed -- obliges me to remain
>   silent about the circumstances in
>   which, therough the person of Vernon
>   Roche, I began working with the
>   Temerian intelligence service. Suffice
>   it to say that there comes a moment in
>   everyone's life when, facing great
>   events, they cannot remain
>   indifferent. And so I could not stand
>   aside as history took shape before my
>   very eyes. My dedication to the cause
>   brought me to Flotsam at the time.
>   There, through an unfortunate incident
>   involving twins at the local brothel,
>   a town guard, a dog, a cat and an oil
>   lamp, I would up on the scaffold in
>   the town square, from which I barely
>   escaped with my life.

Emphasis mine.

This continues to be expanded upon as you progress through the game. If Dandelion claims this is the short version, I'd hate to have to re-type the extended edition...

Comment: I guess this answers the question I was going to ask about whether or not I can get the guy hanged. :(

Comment: @Mana - but if you get Dandelion hanged, who'll be there to pre-test the whores for you in each of the towns you visit?

Answer (score 4):

> Lending emphasis and structure is
>   [Dandelion](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Dandelion), Geralt's [BFF](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bff) who, having a
>   way with words, has written the
>   journal in the game.

[Source](http://n4g.com/user/blogpost/cat/517072).

Comment: Oh, wow, didn't see that coming.

Comment: @Mana Well, who else, if not a word-artist bard? ;)

Comment: It is my personal theory that the books are also written in that way. The books are dandelion's retelling of what happened with the witcher.